# Type mismatch error in complex numerical and logical expression in Inno Script [Code] section

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have revised my function like this:

```pascal
function IsVCRedist32BitNeeded(): boolean;
var
    Major, Minor, Bld, Rbld: Cardinal;
    VCRuntimeInstalled: boolean;
begin
    VCRuntimeInstalled := false; { Assume that VC Runtime is not installed }
    Result := true;

    { Version number is: Major.Minor.Bld.Rbld }
    { Minimum valid version is: 14.14.26429.03 }
    if (RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Major', Major) and
        RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Minor', Minor) and
        RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Bld', Bld) and
        RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Rbld', Rbld)) then
    begin
        VCRuntimeInstalled := true;
    end
    else if (RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Major', Major) and
             RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Minor', Minor) and
             RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Bld', Bld) and
             RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Rbld', Rbld)) then
    begin
        VCRuntimeInstalled := true;
    end;

    if(VCRuntimeInstalled) then
    begin
        { Is the installed version at least 14.14 ? }
        Result := Major < 14 or
                  (Major = 14 and (Minor < 14 or
                  (Minor = 14 and (Bld < 26429 or
                  (Bld = 26429 and Rbld < 3)))));
        { 'true' means we need to run the installer }
        if (Result) then
        begin
            Log('Visual Studio Redist x86 is not already installed');
            Result := True;
        end
        else
            Log(FmtMessage('Visual Studio Redist x86 Version : found v%1.%2.%3.%4', [Major, Minor, Bld, Rbld]));
        end;
    end;
end;
```

It will not compile. It complains about line 978 having a type mismatch:

```pascal
Result := Major < 14 or
          (Major = 14 and (Minor < 14 or
          (Minor = 14 and (Bld < 26429 or
          (Bld = 26429 and Rbld < 3)))));
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pascal Script seems to have a non-standard operator precedence.

Additional brackets will solve this (and it's always better to use them anyway):

```pascal
Result := (Major < 14) or
          ((Major = 14) and ((Minor < 14) or
          ((Minor = 14) and ((Bld < 26429) or
          ((Bld = 26429) and (Rbld < 3))))));
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer as it is closer to the original question. I also think my own testing is flawed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do any check about VC++ runtime.

Simply install them - nothing bad happens if it is already installed. Also the installation takes only few moments so you can continue in doing whatever do in installer (you do not need to wait it to finish).

Also the VC++ runtime required on target machine depends on you application and how you setup it up during development in Visual Studio.

Comment: My application does require them because I do not build statically. And I don't want to attempt to install the runtimes if  they are already on their system. Also, some people have slower computers and it does take a bit of time. One user thought it wasn't installing (but it was). I will keep it as it is. It works perfectly now. :)